# understanding how CSS grid formats with elements inside ES6 template literals

Tags: javascript, css

i have a css grid that has 2 columns and an automatic number of rows, it's filled with data
from a script that takes info from a json array and then forms it into a template and sets the inner html of the grid to that template, and then what i wonder about is how each cell in the grid is filled with a single element from that template, be it a div with other elements nested inside it (it fills one cell) or any other element like an img or a paragraph, how does that happen? here is my code after receiving the JSON array:

```
function setFoods(json){
    if(json.length==0){
        alert(`no results found for ${searchValue}`);
    }else{
    ourGrid.innerHTML=json.map(foodLogic).join("");
    }
    
}

function foodLogic(foodItem){
    return `<div class="imageItem"><img src="${foodItem.image}"></div>
    <div class="infoItem"><h2>${foodItem.title}</h2>
    <h3><a href="./moreInfo.html">More</a></h3></div>
    ` 
}
```

what i understand here is i'm taking the json array, iterating over it with map which returns a new array that each element of it has a value of my template, and then i set the innerHtml of the grid to the new array but how does the grid handle it in such a way?

notice in the picture, each div has it's own cell, and if i didn't use the join i would get the comma (,) from the array in the grid as well and it would take a cell for it's own

[image]

html

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>

    <head>
        <link href="des.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    </head>

    <body>

        <div class="search-header">
            <label for="search">ingredients</label>
            <input type="text" name="search" id="search" placeholder="Enter ingredients here">
            <button onclick="search()">Search</button>
        </div>

        <div class="container">
            <div id="res" class="results">

            </div>
        </div>
        <script src="logic.js"></script>
    </body>

</html>
```

css

```
img{
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    border: 7px solid white;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px gray;
    transform: rotate(-10deg);
}
.container{
    width: 100%;
}
.results{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2,550px);
    grid-auto-flow: row;
    justify-content: center;
    justify-items: center;
    row-gap: 15px;
    
}
.search-header{
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 20
}

.imageItem{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: greenyellow;
    padding: 8px;
}

.infoItem{
    
}
```

Comment: Can you post what the parent HTML container is for the foodLogic structure? And please post your CSS. I have a feeling you are setting the CSSGRID attributes on the parent of the foodLogic, when what you need is another parent DIV above foodLogic for the grid to fire off in the manner you expect.

Comment: edited the post and added my html and css code, i have a set a parent container for my grid as you can see

Answer (score 0):

Try to containerize each set of data like this:

```
function foodLogic(foodItem){
    return `<div class="foodItemContainer"><div class="imageItem"><img src="${foodItem.image}"></div>
    <div class="infoItem"><h2>${foodItem.title}</h2>
    <h3><a href="./moreInfo.html">More</a></h3></div></div>
    ` 
}
```